# How to set swiftmailer setFrom() to show name and surname instead of email? Yii2

Tags: yii2

I know there was a lot of questions related to this, but there were only how to display name or surname instead of email.

So, I'm using `SwiftMailer` to send the contact form emails and instead of just only name, I want to display `name` and `surname` of the form. How should I do that?

```
public function sendEmail($email) 
{
    return Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])
            ->setSubject($this->subject)
            ->setTextBody($this->text)
            ->send();
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just append them if they are separate

```
->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name." ".$this->surname])
```